# How do I use web2py on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, web2py

I'm having a lot of trouble with getting web2py to work on Heroku. I can't even get a basic app to work. Whenever I go to my herokuapp page, it says

> Application Error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

Comment: Have you checked the logs like the error message says? What do the logs say?

Comment: This question is a little too generic, and lack signs of any significant effort on your part to debug the problem. If you can get down to a specific reproducible problem, and show us what you've done so far to try and fix it, then maybe we can help.  A better place to ask this question would be a mailing list or a forum dedicated to Heroku users.  There probably is also some sort of customer support.  Perhaps, if you rephrase your question to __How do I debug my web2py Application on Heroku?__ and show us what you are trying to do (simplified if possible) it would be more appropriate.

Comment: Try http://blog.doersguild.com/post/35049380409/running-web2py-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with the DB setup. By default web2py only supports sqlite or Google App Engine (GAE). It's probably trying to initialize sqlite databases on Heroku's read-only filesystem.

Either disable the DB code temporarily to see if this is indeed the case, or configure a connection to a supported database (MySQL, S3, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "official" Heroku script in [scripts/setup-web2py-heroku.sh](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/setup-web2py-heroku.sh)

Answer (score 0):

Try with a simple wsgi application first. Here is some tutorial: http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial

Web2py will work without any problems if you can run simple wsgi apps.

Comment: site no longer exists